# Android: How to load a list of video from google plus

Tags: android, video, google-plus

Does anyone know where i can get the reference of how to fetch a list of albums of video from google plus to android or is it possible?

I have searched through the web but can't find any references about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google plus REST API is defined at:

- https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/

It lists 4 types of 'resources':

- People
- Activities
- Comments
- Moments

and you can perform 'REST like' queries against them all. The reference above has some good info on this if you follow some of the links.

If you want to see an example of a request to search Google plus for 'Bruce Lee Videos' (for example) enter 'Bruce Lee Video' into the example query box at this link:

- https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search#examples

This should give you a request URI which looks like the one below, and which you could use from your Android App:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?query=Bruce+Lee+Video&maxResults=2&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Note that there is also a Android specific SDK for googleplus:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/package-summary.html

This will allow you get all the Moments for a particular user for example (see method below) but I am not sure if it can be used to search in the same way as the HTTP REST API above:

- load(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, int maxResults, String pageToken, Uri targetUrl, String type, String userId)